# Navier Stokes solution doesnt make sense to me

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I tried solving the Navier Stokes equation for a Newtonian fluid in a pipe.

$\frac{du}{dt}-\frac{\sigma}{\rho}\frac{du}{dx}=g$ with initial condition $u(0,t)=2$ which means that the flow velocity at $x=0$ is $2$.

$\frac{dt}{dx} = -\frac{\rho}{\sigma}\rightarrow t =-\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x+c\rightarrow c = t+\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x $

We the introduce two ned variable $\xi = c , \eta=t$ to put the PDE into canonical form:

$\xi_{t} = 1 ,\xi_{x} =\frac{\rho}{\sigma}  $ and

$\eta_{t}=1,\eta_{x}=0$

$u_{x} = \xi_{x}u_{\xi}+\eta_{x}u_{\eta} = \frac{\rho}{\sigma}u_{\xi}$

$u_{t} =\xi_{t}u_{\xi}+\eta_{t}u_{\eta} = u_{\xi}+u_{\eta}$

Substituting into the original equation we get:

$u_{\eta}=g\rightarrow u(\xi,\eta) = \eta g+f(\xi)$ But $\eta = t$ and $\xi = t+\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x$ so we get $u(x,t) = gt+f(t+\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x)$. By applying the condition $u(0,t)=2\rightarrow gt+f(t)=2\rightarrow f(t) = 2-gt \rightarrow f(t+\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x) = 2-gt-g\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x$ and by substituting $f(t+\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x) \rightarrow u(x,t)  = 2-g\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x$ which doesnt make sense since it can take negative values and predict a negative flow  velocity.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $u(0,t) = 2$, doesn't that mean it will be constant in time? Then $du/dt = 0$, the rest can be separated and integrated and you should end up with velocity of 2 in the whole pipe.

Comment: No It doesn't work like that bcs we know u is only independent of time when x=0.

Comment: You are right. But for transient simulation, you basically need known state at the start. So you should have initial velocity distribution at starting time, not just a value at a point. If the fluid is not compressible, the pipe has constant diameter and you are only interested in mean velocity at each cross section, I don't see a possibility for the velocity to be other than constant in the whole pipe, depending just on time.

Comment: @TomášLétal cant the diameter of the pipe change across x?

Comment: @TomášLétal the flow velocity is 2 at x=0 there isn't any reason why it couldn't be something else when x not equal 0

Comment: If diameter changes, mass flow rate would still be constant, so the velocity would be constrained by this. In other words, you would not be able to just pick any velocity distribution at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia in the Navier Stokes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) the [Cauchy stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) $\sigma = \tau-p$ where $\tau$ describes viscocity and $p$ describes the volumetric pressure

Since we can  make the meaningful assumption that when $|p|>0$ fluid will flow in the pipe $|p|>|\tau|\rightarrow \tau-p<0$ so in my equation the term $-g\frac{\rho}{\sigma}>0$ so $2-g\frac{\rho}{\sigma}x$ cannot be $<0$(for $x>0$)